# Prove $m \text{ mod } n < m/2$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

How do I prove $m \text{ mod } n < m/2$. Seems true for values I tested but how do I prove it in general?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not true for general $m$ and $n$. Take $m=1$ and $n=2$.

More seriously, clearly it is true if $m > 2n$, so you only need to concern yourself with $m \leq 2n$. If $m < n$ then it is clearly false, so the only interesting case is $n \leq m <2n$. But then $m/2 < n$ so $m/2 = m - m/2 > m-n = m$ mod $n$.

So $m$ mod $n < m/2$ if and only if $m \geq n$.

Comment: It is not in fact true if we replace less than with less than or equal to; see, for example, OKS's answer below

Answer (score 1):

It's not true. 2 mod 3 = 2 > 2/2.

Answer (score 0):

I would say the values in the question are ill-defined, as $m \mod n$ is the set $\{r\cdot n + m |r \in \Bbb Z\}$, and no such set is less than any specific number.

Comment: Sometimes a distinction between $m \pmod n$ (the coset) and $m \mod n$ (the least non-negative residue) is made.  Context suggests this is the case here.